# Style folder name in Bold if there's unread mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2010 folder names were bold if there was unread mail in them. In Outlook 2013 this was changed, and by default there's only a bold-blueish number behind the folder.

*How can I once again have **bold folder names** for folders with unread mail in **Outlook 2013**?*

---

Things I've tried, to no avail:

- Search the web. I even landed at our friends at [experts-exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Groupware/Outlook/Q_27944371.html) (scroll down to see the "answers" ;-))
- Conditional formatting tips on the web, but they all come down to [changing other UI bits](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30698/outlook-change-font-color-unread-emails/)
- Custom conditional formatting rules, but they all seem to be about the list of messages (middle pane), not about the list of folders

A Microsoft MVP [mentioned on answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-outlook/outlook-2013-mail-home-page-look/f5f75583-855b-45d3-91fe-84abf3b4cc37?msgId=3eae1085-2af4-4848-aefd-13789e663181) that it's just not possible. That post was from quite a while ago, I would hope that someone has found a solution or workaround by now?

To clarify, here's a screenshot with indication of what I'd like:

[image: Screenshot of mailbox with notes]

Comment: Not an answer since I don't use Outlook 2013 and I'm not able to test this, but you could have a look at [wfSpy](https://github.com/cplotts/wfSpy). Provided that *1)* Outlook 2013 is written using Windows Forms in a supported version of .NET and *2)* wfSpy does what it stays on the tin ("allows you to spy/browse the window hierarchy of a running Windows Forms application [...] and to *change properties* as well") you might be able to pull this off. Obviously this will require some hacking, so as it stands--even if this method works--your current answer is still the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [answer on microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-outlook/outlook-2013-mail-home-page-look/f5f75583-855b-45d3-91fe-84abf3b4cc37?msgId=3eae1085-2af4-4848-aefd-13789e663181) you've found is correct: **this can't be done** in Outlook 2013.

Comment: Same bad design in Outlook 2016. Gnnnnn!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is impossible.  However, you could always revert to Office 2010.

Answer (score -1):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpropreview/thread/88f55ec6-65a9-46bb-81cf-96bc57a48585/

View->View Settings->Conditional->New Mail
Change the font.

Comment: Wouldn't such a rule be for changing the font of *items* in the other panes? In any case, with just the instructions you've posted it's kinda hard to see what's needed. Can you include some more details, perhaps add a screenshot or two of how this works and the end result?